# I accidentally disabled a Windows 10 service, now I can't start processes as administrator

Tags: windows-10, services

I can't start sc, cmd as administrator, can't access services.msc.

Also some non-administrator applications are not starting.

Comment: What happens if you boot in safe mode

Comment: You are probably referring to the "Application Information" service. It should be as simple as a registry edit. Do you have a Windows DVD/USB drive at hand?